# How to dm a user with a discord.js bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot using discord.js and I want to do a command like this one:

```
t!mp "text" user
```

The prefix is `t!`. The `"text"` is the message content and the user is at the end of the command. This commands just send a direct message to the tagged user. How can I recreate a command like this?

Comment: You can use regex on messages https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.users.find(t => t.id == "The Users ID").send("Your message");
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a DM to a user, use

```
<Member>.send(“text”)
```

You can get the mentioned user from `message.mentions.members.first()`

For the text part, split `message.content`, select what you want with indexing, then `.join(“ “)`

Comment: can I have an example? I've try something but didn't work :(